# How to set a PNG file to an ImageView?

Tags: android, png, imageview, drawable

I have a file called `nochart.png` in `/drawable`.

How can I set this to an `ImageView`?

```
chartImageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.nochart);
```

Does not compile.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use:

```java
chartImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.nochart);
```

Comment: Tried this, but still crashed when using a `.png` file. If I try the same thing with a `.jpeg` file, it works. The same is true (i.e crash) if I try `android:background="@drawable/image_name"` with a `.png` file, but works with `.jpeg`s. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed. The problem was the image size itself; it was too large. Scaling the image to be smaller did the trick and works from the XML file directly, i.e.  `android:background="@drawable/image_name"`

Answer (score 3):

you can also set the image using an xml file with the following attriblute

```
android:src="@drawable/nochart"
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It seems that ImageView can't load a png by default.

Comment: Doing this works for me ***if*** I'm using a `.jpeg` file. It crashes with a `.png` file.

Comment: Scratch my last comment. My problem was the image size itself; it was too large. Scaling the image to be smaller did the trick and works from the XML file directly, i.e. `android:background="@drawable/image_name"` as a `.png` file.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The solution for me was to move the ".png" from "drawable-21" to "drawable".

Answer (score 1):

just put your .png file in mipmap folder